# Issue while rendering Flask/Jinja2/Mongodb based date to highchart

Tags: javascript, mongodb, flask, highcharts, jinja2

The issue is highchart is not able to render dates which is stored in monogdb. My date format is 2019-03-15T12:58:02. And below is the code what I am rendering in my javascript/highchart

Below is the date which is being stored in my mongodb

```
{'setnumlow': 6.0, 'setnum': 11.8, 'setnumdate': u'2019-03-15T12:58:02', 'setnumhigh': 18.0}
```

And My javascript code is shown below:

```
var ranges = [
        {% for i in mobu %}
        [{{ i.setnumdate }},{{ i.setnumlow }},{{ i.setnumhigh }}],  
        {% endfor %} 
        ],
```

My knowledge on javascript/highchart is less, so I am not sure how should I render it. Is there a way to convert the date to javascript format (on which highchart understands)

My flask code

```
for i in set2:
                mobu.append({
                "setnumdate":(i['date']),
                "setnum":(i['setnum']),
                "setnumhigh":(i['setnumhigh']),
                "setnumlow":(i['setnumlow'])
                })
```

Below is the output which I am getting from "Inspect Element"

[image]

So without touching the mongodb database, how can i convert the date to understandable javascript/highchart format

Comment: you really should prepare a JSON in your flask route and send that JSON to be rendered by highcharts instead of looping in your html

Comment: For `datetime` axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970. So you should convert your dates first and then pass them to `ranges` array as a timestamp.